# What do Error Status Report codes mean on the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

If you've had any networking problems on the 360, done a network test then pressed Y for detailed status, you've seen a dialog like this (this one's not mine; thanks google image search):

[image: Error Status Report]

What do all these codes mean? I don't think Microsoft tech support will tell us, perhaps for job security reasons.
I can guess some of them:

- `T` = network `T`ype (wired / wireless)
- `A` = private `A`ddress / subnet mask
- `G` = `G`ateway
- `D` = `D`NS1 / DNS2
- `N` = wireless access point `N`ame (SSID)
- `S` = wireless `S`ecurity type

What about W, X, Y, Z, ID, L, Q and C? I think Q might be the error code, and MS does have an [**error code search**](http://support.xbox.com/error-code-lookup) page, but the explanation for code 80070435 (with I've had with a wired connection) is hopelessly uninformative.

Does anyone have any more information?

Comment: C is your router's wireless channel

Answer (score 4):

W: Hardware setup

X: Connection End - Means connection to X-box live servers has failed

Y: Internet setup type 00A8 - E840 U.S.A. Version Wireless Receiver for X-Box 360 Console. Others would be Ethernet cable or out of U.S.A. model of receiver.

Z: X-Box Policy Offenses. 0000 - 0000 = No X-box offenses. Any other = Ban or Suspension

[Source](http://www.avforums.com/forums/xbox-live/1025013-problem-xbox-live.html)

Comment: Great. Can you link to a source for this info?

Comment: Still no answer for some of the letters? My C is six. That is what brought me to this page.

Comment: _Perhaps_ C stands for control code to make sure the information was relayed correctly?